# nginx: [emerg] unknown "upstream_connect_time" variable

Tags: nginx

I'm working with `nginx/1.6.0` and I want to log `upstream_connect_time` and  `upstream_header_time` with settings as below:

```
log_format  working_p '$remote_addr - $host [$time_local]\t'
                      '$request" $status $body_bytes_sent\t'
                      '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"\t'
                      'rt=$request_time uct="$upstream_connect_time" uht="$upstream_header_time" urt="$upstream_response_time"\t'
                      '$http_x_forwarded_for ';
```

But I always get error

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown "upstream_connect_time" variable
test nginx conf fail. please check it first, we won't reload it
```

How can I get `upstream_connect_time` as expected?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation this is available on `1.9.1+`

> $upstream_connect_time
> keeps time spent on establishing a connection with the upstream server (1.9.1); the time is kept in seconds with millisecond resolution. In case of SSL, includes time spent on handshake. Times of several connections are separated by commas and colons like addresses in the $upstream_addr variable.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_connect_time

Comment: Thanks for replying and could you tell me how can I get the same value in `1.6.0`?

Comment: You can't, you need to upgrade your nginx